# How make a sequelize query, that paginates correctly with the includes conditions?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize query, my goal is to have all data project, but only those in which project_status matches the current_status_id, which is nested in another model CodePhaseType.

These are the current relations:

```
db.project.hasMany(
  db.projectStatus,
  { foreignKey: 'project_id' }
);
db.project.hasMany(
  db.projectStatus,
  { foreignKey: 'project_status_id',sourceKey: "current_project_status_id",
  as: 'currentId' } 
);


db.projectStatus.belongsTo(
  db.codePhaseType,
  { foreignKey: 'code_phase_type_id' }
);
db.codePhaseType.belongsTo(
  db.codeStatusType,
  { foreignKey: 'code_status_type_id' }
);
db.codePhaseType.belongsTo(
  db.codeProjectType,
  { foreignKey: 'code_project_type_id' }
);
```

This is the query that I tried:

```
Project.findAll({
      where: where,
      limit,
      offset,
      separate: true,
      attributes: [
        "project_id",
        "project_name",
        "description",
        "onbase_project_number",
        "created_date",
        'code_project_type_id',
        'current_project_status_id',
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: ProjectStatus,
          as: 'currentId',
          include: {
            model: CodePhaseType,
            where: { code_status_type_id: +filter },
          }
        }
      ]
      ,
      order: [['created_date', 'DESC']]
    })
```

With this query I get all projects that match the where condition inside include of CodePhaseType.
Nonetheless, the problem is with pagination.
The value for the offset is calculated like this:
const offset = (page - 1) * limit;

Lets say I query page 1, limit 100. I get 38 projects.
So if I would get page 4, limit 5, I should get projects, but its empty.

The query generated is this:

```
SELECT 
  [project].*,
  ...
  [project].[code_project_type_id],
  [project].[current_project_status_id]
  FROM (
    SELECT TOP 15 * FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY [project].[created_date] DESC
      ) as row_num, *
      FROM [project] AS [project]) AS [project]
      WHERE row_num > 45
  ) AS [project]
  WHERE (
    SELECT TOP 1 [currentId].[project_status_id]
    FROM [project_status] AS [currentId]
    INNER JOIN [code_phase_type] AS [code_phase_type] ON [currentId].[code_phase_type_id] = [code_phase_type].[code_phase_type_id] AND [code_phase_type].[code_status_type_id] = 1
    WHERE (
      [currentId].[project_status_id] = [project].[current_project_status_id]
    ) 
  ) IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY [project].[created_date] DESC
  ) AS [project]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [project_cost] AS [project_costs] ON [project].[project_id] = [project_costs].[project_id]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ( [project_status] AS [currentId]
  INNER JOIN [code_phase_type] AS [currentId->code_phase_type] ON [currentId].[code_phase_type_id] = [currentId->code_phase_type].[code_phase_type_id]
  AND [currentId->code_phase_type].[code_status_type_id] = 1 ) ON [project].[current_project_status_id] = [currentId].[project_status_id]
  ORDER BY [project].[created_date] DESC;
```

So the pagination segment seems to be before the condition, so it doesn't work good.

I am using 5.21.7 sequelize version.

Comment: Required and separate are not compatible, required makes an inner join, and separate create another query.

Comment: You should use `required: true` only without `separate: true`

Comment: try to use a subquery to filter the projects with the desired condition and then apply pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem you mention about the limit and offset problem in this [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7344).

Basically this is caused because the conditionals on the where clause are not being used during the offsetting.

The issue seems to be solved now by using `subQuery: false`, but unfortunately it is available only in the version 6.

A query generated on version 6 would look like this:

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 PERCENT [project].[project_id],
    ...
    [project].[code_project_type_id],
    [project].[current_project_status_id],
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 5 *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        ORDER BY
                            [project].[created_date] DESC
                    ) as row_num,
                    [project].*
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            DISTINCT [project].*
                        FROM
                            [project] AS [project]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [project_cost] AS [project_costs] ON [project].[project_id] = [project_costs].[project_id]
                            INNER JOIN [project_status] AS [currentId] ON [project].[current_project_status_id] = [currentId].[project_status_id]
                            INNER JOIN [code_phase_type] AS [currentId->code_phase_type] ON [currentId].[code_phase_type_id] = [currentId->code_phase_type].[code_phase_type_id]
                            AND [currentId->code_phase_type].[code_status_type_id] = 1
                    ) AS [project]
            ) AS [project]
        WHERE
            row_num > 35
    ) AS [project]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [project_cost] AS [project_costs] ON [project].[project_id] = [project_costs].[project_id]
    INNER JOIN [project_status] AS [currentId] ON [project].[current_project_status_id] = [currentId].[project_status_id]
    INNER JOIN [code_phase_type] AS [currentId->code_phase_type] ON [currentId].[code_phase_type_id] = [currentId->code_phase_type].[code_phase_type_id]
    AND [currentId->code_phase_type].[code_status_type_id] = 1
ORDER BY
    [project].[created_date] DESC
```

As you can see it, the conditional where is used in both count subquery and project query.